# Making BigQuery tables accessible without service accounts

Tags: google-bigquery

So I have a few BigQuery tables that I want to make accessible to query through python for a fairly large amount of users (I'd say around the ball park of 500 to be safe). I know the typical method to make them accessible through a service account and then pass a JSON key to those people. But I'd like to avoid that since the limit for service accounts through Google is 100. I would like to be able to identify users activity in terms of BigQuery usage, so hence I have the issue.

Is there another way to handle this?

I've been exploring making my own API and then making that endpoint accessible through generated API keys. I've also been looking into the IAM policy but unsure if I should be tuning that.

Comment: You have 500 users, you cannot trust to give service accounts. Thus the way to create a REST API with cloud functions. You need to implement all security, generated API keys is a good way. You can include the secret API keys in the cloud function code to make it easier for you. Limit the runs per API key per day. If possible code the tables hard inside your API. Please be careful with user input data. If you expect a list of columns to be returned, here someone could inject code in your BigQuery doing bad things.

Comment: You can create google group, add it to the project and share table to a group. Then they can login via OAuth2

Comment: Ok I tried setting up a API through API Gateway to Cloud functions, then authenticating through API keys. That actually worked great, until I queried one of our larger tables and I believe I hit the 10mb quota that is set on Cloud functions through HTTP requests. How should I be arranging this differently to allow for those tables? I want to say the biggest table would 9 mb (logical bytes in BigQuery) but these could grow in size. Would possibly cutting down the size of the table an option too?